# How to create a function (R Programming) that is relevant for this example

Tags: r

I have a homework / assignment question that needs to be looked at and if you could please provide me with some help, it will be much appreciated.

I have a file something like this shown below:
I've only selected the first 20 lines as there is more than 250 lines.

The following line tells us that "NZ1" crossed the start line (at line 14 - shown below)

**11:10:01 NZ1 Crossed Start Line**

and the following is the finish line (at line 109 - not shown below)

**11:35:16 NZ1 Crossed Finished Line**

What I need to do is to create a function called **getTimes()**, that takes the name of a boat (e.g. NZ1, US1 is a boat) and returns the start and finish times for that boat.

> txtFile <- readLines("130901_chatter.txt")
>
> txtFile[1:20]
>
> [1] "Chatter Log, Sun 1 Sept 2013"
>    [2] "Red Bull Youth AC, Races 1 & 2"
>    [3] ""
>    [4] "10:35:59 MDS redbull yacht data is public"
>    [5] "10:44:47 TIM Red Bull Youth America's Cup Race Day 1, Sun 1 Sep 2013"
>    [6] "10:45:03 WND Wind 255 at 14.2 kts, 14.2 kts peak"
>    [7] "10:45:41 TIM Race 1 starts at 11:10 PDT, 10 yachts racing, 7 legs"
>    [8] "10:46:58 GER Yankee Flag"
>    [9] "10:47:12 UMP GER No Penalty"
>   [10] "10:55:03 WND Wind 255 at 14.5 kts, 16.7 kts peak"
>   [11] "11:05:03 WND Wind 245 at 13.8 kts, 14.9 kts peak"
>   [12] "11:07:00 Race 1 (GER,SUI,NZ2,US1,US2,POR,FRA,AUS,NZ1,SWE): Warning, 3:00 until start"
>   [13] "11:10:00 Race 1 (GER,SUI,NZ2,US1,US2,POR,FRA,AUS,NZ1,SWE): Started"
>   [14] "11:10:01 NZ1 Crossed Start Line"
>   [15] "11:10:01 US1 Crossed Start Line"
>   [16] "11:10:01 US2 Crossed Start Line"
>   [17] "11:10:02 FRA Crossed Start Line"
>   [18] "11:10:02 GER Crossed Start Line"
>   [19] "11:10:02 SUI Crossed Start Line"
>   [20] "11:10:02 NZ2 Crossed Start Line"

Could you please check my code below?

```
startResults <- function(filenames){
filess <- readLines(filenames)
startLines <- grep("NZ1 Cross", filess)
startText <- filess[startLines] 
leelee <- startText[1:2]
ohSeung<-substr(leelee, 1,9)
}

crossStart<-startResults("130901_chatter.txt")

getTimes<-function(raceIDs){
raceIDs = crossStart
return(raceIDs)
}
getTimes("NZ1")
```

If I run the code above, I get the result for NZ1. However, I need to get the result for other boats as well but not too sure how to get it.

Oh, and this is how my raceIDs look like:

> raceIDs
>       [1] "GER" "SUI" "NZ2" "US1" "US2" "POR" "FRA" "AUS" "NZ1" "SWE"

I should be getting something like this if the function is correct (start time and finish time of the boat):

```
> getTimes("NZ1")
[1] "11:10:01" "11:35:16"

> getTimes("US1")
[1] "11:10:01" "11:33:29"

> getTimes("NZ2")
[1] "11:10:02" "11:34:12"
```

I believe my function only calculates "NZ1" but not any other boats.

Any helps would be much appreciated!

Comment: Maybe returning `ohSeung` in your first function?

Comment: Hint: What in `startResults` do you need to change to get the results for `US1`? Can you turn that into a function parameter?

Comment: This is a homework, right? http://stat220.stat.auckland.ac.nz/stats380/2013/notes/assign02.pdf

Comment: Yes..Just need to do Q8

Comment: I hope you've read and followed http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. I wasn't aware of that. I have edited my posting now. Any helps if available please?

Comment: @BlueMagister's advice is good and sound - it points in the right direction. I suggest you follow it.

Comment: What I have tried is when I use `grep("US1 Cross")` I get the results for `US1`. But I don't want to repeat myself 10 times and instead I believe that I need to use a loop but don't know how :(

Comment: Can you do for `US1` what you did with your function parameter `filenames`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oboy! ... a sailing question! The principle here is to identify the patterns in the text that define a useful line and then segment the line. Take a look at

"11:10:01 NZ1 Crossed Start Line" and those that follow and then see that all the lines with useful data have "Crossed" in them. And they have a pattern for time and a pattern for the team acronym. First create a logical vector that is a "start line" for a particular boat using `grepl`. Make it more general than you have done so far so you will be able to pass that vector of boat ID's using sapply to the function:

```
# You already have the text in memory, so no need to load it every time
startResults <- function( boatID){
     startLines <- grepl(paste(boatID, "Cross", sep=" "), txtFile)
     startText <- txtFile[startLines] 
     ## leelee <- startText[1:2]  # that looks wrong
     substr(startText, 1,9)
}
```

There are probably slicker ways to do this all with regex patterns but this is a start. You now get to make a corresponding end-times functions and string the rest of it together to answer  the question.